# Executing Lua script with a for-loop on the command line

Tags: lua

I have a Lua program in a file:

```
$ cat three.lua
for i = 1, 3 do print(i) end
```

It runs great with Lua 5.3:

```
$ lua three.lua
1
2
3
```

But I cannot run it on the command line with `-e`:

```
$ lua -e 'for i = 1, 3 do print(i) end'
lua5.3: (command line):1: <name> expected near <eof>
```

Simpler programs work fine with `-e`:

```
$ lua -e 'print("Hello");print("World")'
Hello
World
```

It seems Lua's script building `-e` does not like the structured `for` statement with the terminating `end`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For Linux, it works the way you have it.  For Windows, you need double quotes.

Comment: Thanks. I'm on macOS and have installed Lua 5.3. from homebrew. Unfortunately double quotes do not work either. This script used to work with Lua 5.2. I might have a bad installation, or something changed in 5.3.

Comment: Figured it out. Homebrew changed so that `brew install lua` does NOT install Lua 5.3!  ARRRRRGGGHHH. So you have to `brew install lua5.3`, which makes an executable called `lua5.3` (NOT `lua`!!!). Because I found this awful, I made my own `lua` script that invokes lua5.3. But I made it wrong. I made it say `lua5.3 $@` instead of `lua5.3 "$@"`. So it was not Lua's fault, but mine. I'm still very disappointed with the maintainers of Lua homebrew formula, but I'm sure they had their reasons, which were more important than my own desires.

Answer (score 0):

This works as expected on macOS using Lua 5.3.4.